# Como tornar responsivo

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

Tenho esse projeto mais avançado , porem deixei ele liso para poder facilitar a visualização e para vocês me ajudarem =D , tentei de tudo possível usando o media queries porem nada, quero que a janela se ajuste em qualquer tela e o problema maior estar no leitor do pdf que não arrasta com nada, meu css não é la essa coisas ai complica.

Se eu colocar o codigo todo aqui vai ficar enorme, então disponibilizei no github, agradeço desde ja.

https://github.com/rodrigoscsx/PROJETO?

Comment: Cara. Te falar que responsividade não é muito uma coisa que você pega no final assim e joga em cima. Seu projeto parece estar trabalhado de uma forma muito trancada já. A melhor forma de fazer algo responsivo é ir pensando nisso desde o início. Não é a toa que existe o termo "mobile first".

Comment: Eu concordo em tudo que o Leon Freire disse. *Mobile first*!!! A parte boa é que você pode usar *frameworks* que fazem o trabalho: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [Foudation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), [Cardinal](http://cardinalcss.com/), [Pure](https://purecss.io/), etc. Além disso, seu layout deve ser fluido (usar proporções - %, vw, vh, etc. - mais do que medidas absolutas - px, pt, etc.

Comment: sim sim verdade @LeonFreire porem eu entrei no projeto depois ai fiquei com o pepino de resolver o responsivo, e o layout teria que ser assim. è capaz de mudar ainda?

Comment: Teria que ter um CSS forte aí. Primeira coisa que eu percebi quando abri o index.html é que está cheio de `position: fixed`. Isso é horrível pra responsividade. Se quiser manter assim, você vai ter que retirá-los pelo menos nos media queries e trabalhar mais com float e com as medidas citadas acima. **Exemplo:** Você falou do iframe que não se mexe. Mas teu `#contentMeioiFrame` está com `position: fixed;` e `left: 250px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, o meu comentário ficou grande demais, então eu vou deixá-lo aqui.

É possível sim. Mas comece com o ***mobile***, depois telas cada vez maiores, até o *desktop* (que já existe no sue caso, aparentemente). Defina o layout que você quer e preste atenção no range de definições (**320×240 até 640×960**).

Use as [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) apropriadamente. Eu não vou escrever nenhuma aqui, mas saiba que o [**CSS Tricks**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) (mais que recomendado) já tem todos os *snippets* mais usados.

**!!! Preste atenção !!!**

1. Alguns elementos do seu *site* simplesmente não vão existir na versão mobile, você tem que removê-los, seja por falta de espaço ou por outro fator, e isso está ***okay***!

1.1 Pense em como o menu vai ser mostrado. Veja esse exemplo do [***CSS Tricks***](https://css-tricks.com/convert-menu-to-dropdown/)

2. A versão *mobile* é sempre aquela que oferece um toque de botão, nada mais (figurativo), não deixa o cliente pensar (*don't make me think principle*) E.g.: Se as funcionalidades do site estão numa área que precisa de *login*, mostre o *login* logo de cara, não precisa mostrar o *slider*, por exemplo.
3. Pesquise por *plugins* para facilitar seu serviço. Existem muitos como o [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

*Tip*: Escreva o *CSS* para cada tipo de tela que você quer suportar em arquivos .CSS separados, isso vai ajudar na manutenção.